# ¿Cómo programar acciones a los botones del dispositivo con flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Soy nueva en flutter, he investigado y encontré una librería que me permite acceder a los eventos de los botones del dispositivo (hardware_buttons), busco saber (si se puede) los mecanismos de botones ya asignados, y asignar una acción a cierto mecanismo de botones en el dispositivo(como el de captura de pantalla) para cuando el usuario ejecute dicho mecanismo de botones, se realice una acción. Cómo podría asignar esa configuración en el dispositivo? Gracias.

Comment: No sé mucho de flutter, pero más específicamente cuándo quieres que funcione? Solo dentro de la aplicación o fiera también?

Comment: Y como se llama la librería?

Comment: Tanto fuera como dentro de la aplicación. La librería se llama hardware_buttons